# What might cause getaddrinfo() to return an error code of "1"?

Tags: c, network-programming, berkeley-sockets

More or less what it says in the title. I have a call to getaddrinfo like so:

```
struct addrinfo crossplat, *actual_addr;
crossplat.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //IPv4 or IPv6.
crossplat.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; 

if(int i = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8000", &crossplat, &actual_addr)!=0){
    cerr << "error code " << i << " received. Meaning: "<<  gai_strerror(i) << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Which proudly prints:

```
error code 1 received. Meaning: Unknown error
```

on my system.

The getaddrinfo man page on my system:

```
RETURN VALUE
   getaddrinfo() returns 0 if it succeeds, or one of the following 
   nonzero error codes:

   EAI_ADDRFAMILY....


   ...The gai_strerror() function translates these error codes to a 
       human readable string, suitable for error reporting.
```

Which suggests to me that all non-zero codes returned by getaddrinfo should be one of the listed EAI_* family codes. Searching online suggests that gai_strerror() will only return "Unknown error" when it is passed an error code which is *not* a member of the EAI_* family, which would seem to rule out "1" being such a code.

Apparently I'm doing something rather wrong here, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This expression is a syntax error in C, but assuming you are using C++ it's not grouped how you're expecting:

```
if (int i = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8000", &crossplat, &actual_addr)!=0){
```

This will assign the result of `getaddrinfo("localhost", "8000", &crossplat, &actual_addr) != 0` to `i`, which is always either 0 or 1.  Any non-zero return by `getaddrinfo()` will leave `i` with the value of 1.

You need to declare `i` earlier so that you can paranthesize the assignment:

```
int i;
if ((i = getaddrinfo("localhost", "8000", &crossplat, &actual_addr)) != 0) {
```

(of course, having done this you'd probably also move the `getaddrinfo()` call to the initializer of `i`).

Comment: Ah, that's done it nicely. I usually write C, but have to compile with g++ for this project, which led me to take advantage of poorly understood features. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @JohnDoucette Using assignment inside conditions is a very effective way to generate hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need to initialise `crossplat.ai_protocol`.  The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo) section on the *hints* argument mentions this being used in addition to the `addrinfo` members you already initialise.

You might also need to initialise `crossplat.ai_flags`.  It'd probably be easier to just memset the whole structure:

```
struct addrinfo crossplat, *actual_addr;
memset(&crossplat, 0, sizeof(crossplat));
crossplat.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC; //IPv4 or IPv6.
crossplat.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
```

Comment: Yep, that was it. Ought to have spotted that myself! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In `getaddrinfo.h` : `#define EAI_ADDRFAMILY 1`, which means : address family for hostname not supported

Comment: Interesting, but if this is the case, why doesn't gai_strerror correctly translate it on my system?

Comment: don't know exactly, but in gai_strerror() man page EAI_ADDRFAMILY ins't listed, even if it is defined in netdb.h. Maybe it ignores the error but that would be strange...

Comment: The value of `EAI_ADDRFAMILY` varies for different C libraries - for example for mine it is -9.